# Trouble establishing a secured connection to a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

After buying a domain through Route 53 and starting my NodeJS app on an EC2 instance, I followed [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/getting-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-aws-a-how-to-guide-6ef29e576d22) to create an SSL certificate for my website.

Yet whenever I open it, I still get the "Your connection is not secured" warning on Chrome.

Am I missing something?

In the AWS Certificate Manager I have the certificate for my domain.

My LB listens for ports 80 and 443 and it has my SSL certificate associated with port 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: how you opening the connection?using DNS or LB endpoint? did you add redirect http to https?

Comment: Does the URL you are opening in Chrome match the domain name on the SSL certificate?

Comment: @Adiii using the LB endpoint. I didn't redirect HTTP to HTTPS, am i supposed to? (sorry, i'm just kind of new to this)

Comment: @MarkB yes it does.

Comment: your certificate is against `domain name` so it will not work for LB endpoint. you should open the application using Domain name, not the LB endpoint

Comment: Even after adding my domain name as an A record in my Route 53 settings and accessing the website using `www.mydomain.com` i got the same "connection is not secured" message.

Comment: try to open `https://your_domainname.com` , yes redirect is better to auto redirect https if someone hit http://example.com

Comment: go to certificate setting and double the certificate is it `*.yourdomain.com` or `yourdomain.com`

Comment: It's for `yourdomain.com` and `www.yourdomain.com`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200662/discussion-between-adiii-and-gambit2007).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference to our discussion, it works fine when sepcify `https` in URL, so all you need to redirect `http` traffic to `https` in LB rule.

Creating an HTTP to HTTPS redirection rule happens in the Listener, as a Rule. I assume that you’re already familiar with setting up a basic ALB, Target Group, and Listener. Once you’ve created a Listener, you can add a new rule to it to handle the redirection.

[image]

The redirection itself happens in the action section. Select Redirect to in the action section.

Since we just need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, we’ll leave the host, path, and query as-is, and just change the protocol to HTTPS and the port to 443.

Now all your incoming port 80 traffic will now be redirected to 443.

You can further check [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/elastic-load-balancing-announces-support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer/) and [here](https://www.fischco.org/technica/2018/aws-alb-redirects/)